# What's the meaning and origin of "Herp Derp"?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I have seen, usually in Internet meme jokes, the term "herp derp" being used in a derogatory sense, but I don't know what it means exactly — apart from the fact that it seems to be related to dumbness or irrelevant statements.

What does it mean exactly? Is it some kind of slang? What are its origins and meaning?

(Urban Dictionary doesn't help much in this case).

Comment: -1 Inadequate background research effort? http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/harp-darp-herp-derp -- makes for interesting reading.

Comment: @Kris Know Your Meme is not listed in the list of commonly-available references maintained on this site's meta (http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available-online). Yes, it's possible for a user to look the answer up there, but it's not a resource everyone knows about in the same way that a dictionary or Wikipedia is, and a user who's unfamiliar with it could be excused for assuming that a site on the "Cheezburger Network" isn't a reliable reference.

Comment: @user867 https://www.google.com/webhp?#q="herp-derp" I don't think Google Search is too much of home work. joulesm found it, OP could.

Comment: @Kris What about the last 22 words of my comment?

Comment: @user867 I don't think I needed to comment on that part. Please read the FAQ if you like more details. http://english.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: @Kris Ah, fair point. The list linked in the FAQ (which I previously thought was the same as the one I linked) doesn't include Know Your Meme, but it does include Google, which comes up with the answer within the first few hits. Carry on!

Comment: @user867, you are absolutely correct. [Google is not General Reference](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2374/google-is-not-general-reference), and this question cannot be answered by commonly available references as they are defined here.

Comment: @phenry Wait, I am? Huh, I thought Kris had successfully rebutted my point. Thanks for the update.

Comment: means hello good sir and how are you?

Comment: i agree good sir

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [Know Your Meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/harp-darp-herp-derp), "herp derp" is *an expression used to indicate that someone is unintelligent or making ignorant statements*.

It is derived from [*derp*](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/derp), which apparently was first used in a 1998 movie called *[BASEketball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASEketball)*.

Comment: ...and further, *derp* is derived from *der + excrescent /p/*, where the excrescent /p/ is the same one found in *yup*,*nope*, and *wellp*.

Comment: @MarkBeadles- I like *excrescent*.  Let's see if I can remember it.

Comment: @mark - do you have a reference for that (e.g. the screenwriters) ?